# Is the Tao framework dead?

Tags: c#, .net, opentk, tao-framework

I'm looking into experimenting with Tao but I am somewhat put-off by its dead-looking state. It hasn't been updated since 2008 and it looks like their website stopped functioning at roughly the same time.

Does anyone have any information on the current situation or know of its stability?

Comment: ...being busy rendering.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The project was superseded by OpenTK ([http://www.opentk.com/](http://www.opentk.com))

From the FAQ:

"**Will my Tao project run on OpenTK?**

Starting with version 0.9.9-2, OpenTK is compatible with Tao.OpenGl, Tao.OpenAl and Tao.Platform.Windows.SimpleOpenGlControl. Simply replace your Tao.OpenGl, Tao.OpenAl and Tao.Platform.Windows references with OpenTK and OpenTK.Compatibility and your project will as before, while gaining advantage of all OpenTK features."

Comment: OpenTK doesn't include FFmpeg, unfortunately.

Comment: OpenTK looks just as dead. Hasn't been touched in over a year.

Comment: @Mark: [This blogpost](http://www.opentk.com/opentk-1.1-beta4-released-with-joystick-and-gamepad-input) indicates that a new beta version was released on Jan 3, 2014, about 10 days ago. The [blog history](http://www.opentk.com/blog) shows some activity at least every 2 months, also throughout 2013.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same question recently so:
Tao Classic is the direct continuation of the abandoned Tao Framework open source project. http://tc.insaneidea.hu/

Answer (score 1):

This continuation of OpenTk is current as of Nov 2015:

https://github.com/opentk/opentk